# pyzmq compiling error

Tags: compiling

Executing instruction from the following portal,

https://gns3.com/discussions/how-to-install-gns3-1-2-3-on-ubu

but ubutu 12.04 throws error in the pyzmq stage, here the error report.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/opt/gns3/downloads/pyzmq$ sudo python3.3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running configure
************************************************
Using bundled libzmq
already have bundled/zeromq
already have platform.hpp
************************************************
checking for timer_create
cc -c /tmp/timer_create_6e3wa.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/tmp/timer_create_6e3wa.o
cc build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/tmp/timer_create_6e3wa.o -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/a.out
build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/tmp/timer_create_6e3wa.o: In function `main':
timer_create_6e3wa.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `timer_create'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no timer_create, linking librt
************************************************
skipping 'zmq/devices/monitoredqueue.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/backend/cython/_device.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/backend/cython/_poll.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/backend/cython/_version.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/backend/cython/constants.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
cythoning zmq/backend/cython/context.pyx to zmq/backend/cython/context.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    def underlying(self):
        """The address of the underlying libzmq context"""
        return <size_t     self.handle

    # backward-compat, though nobody is using it
    _handle = underlying
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

zmq/backend/cython/context.pyx:119:24: 'underlying' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
building 'zmq.backend.cython.context' extension
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -    Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DHAVE_SYS_UN_H=1 -Ibundled/zeromq/include -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/    cython -Izmq/devices -I/usr/include/python3.3m -c zmq/backend/cython/context.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/zmq/backend/cython/context.o
zmq/backend/cython/context.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
ubuntu@ubuntu:/opt/gns3/downloads/pyzmq$
```

Appreciate all your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the development version of Cython (0.24a). If you install a stable version of Cython (0.23):

```
python3.3 -m pip install cython
```

you should be okay.

Since you already have the repository checked out, you can check out the git branch, as well, and proceed with installation:

```
git checkout 0.23.4
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: It also fails with the same error with Cython 0.24.1 which is stable. Latest version that works is 0.23.5

Comment: The current version of pyzmq (15.4) works with the current version of Cython (0.24.1), as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was introduced by [cython@`9b04560`](https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/9b045609cd976c1479b6f7f9fda6c742875a83ee), which changes the way `@property` nodes are handled. [@minrk](https://askubuntu.com/users/412173/minrk) has removed the offending line in [zeromq@`659f921`](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/commit/659f9211aad1565543e26ef6877456d017c9d5bb), so with a recent checkout of zeromq the problem should be gone.